# How to add "1px" without starting from "0px"?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a parallax background, with the parallax background moving as a different speed from the content. I've modified this jQuery code from Codepen slightly so that 1px is added to the 'background-position-y' when the page is scrolled.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(window).scroll(function(e) {
            parallax();
        });

        function parallax() {
            var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('.wsite-section-bg-image').css('background-position-y', -(scrolled * 0.1) + 'px');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The 'background-position-y' is already set for the parallax background with CSS, but when the jQuery code fires, it starts the background-position-y from "0" instead of its inherent CSS position, causing an abrupt jerk in the image.

What can be added to this code so that the jQuery code adds '1px' to the 'background-position-y's' inherent CSS position and not start it from "0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try something different. I have never seen css background-position-y and think this is a Internet Explorer special. This method bypasses the whole zero problem

```
<script>
function scrollSomething () {
    var x = $(document).scrollTop();
    // < 1 for slower scroll and > 1 for faster scroll
    var scrollSpeed1 = x * 0.7;
    var scrollSpeed2 = x * 0.5;
    var scrollSpeed3 = x * 1.25;
    var hBckgd1 = $(".background1").height(); // get height
    var hBckgd2 = $(".background2").height(); // get height
    $("background1")css({"top": scrollSpeed1 + "px"});
    $("background2")css({"top": scrollSpeed2 + hBckgd1 + "px"});
    $("background3")css({"top": scrollSpeed3 + hBckgd1 + hBckgd2 + "px"});
    }
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollSomething);
</script>
```

Comment: I'll have multiple parallax backgrounds on the same page and each background will be at a different 'background-position-y'. I don't want to give all backgrounds the same 'background-position-y'. I'd rather the jQuery code figure it out on its own, if possible.

Comment: Alright, going to edit the code above to deal with multiple backgrounds. check within 3 minutes or so.

Comment: Obviously, the second and third background do not start where the first background starts, so you will have to get the height of background 1 and the height of background 2 (with jQuery .height()). Set background 2 to (scrollSpeed2 + heightBackground1) and set background 3 to (scrollSpeed3 + heightBackground1 + heightBackground2)

Comment: Hey Kobbe, "background-position-y" is just the "y" coordinate for the CSS "background-position".

Comment: I tried the code you created -- which I do greatly appreciate -- but no go. No parallax scrolling at all. I need to mess around with this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: This is the exact code I used to make this website https://eyesonpi.com.

Comment: Hey, @Kobbe, I used your new code and added some additional CSS to it and it's working perfectly! Thank you so much for your time and code!

Comment: Great to hear that. What I forgot to add is that in order to set "top" for background2 and background3 you have to add the height of all elements above background2 and above background3 for it to work. You can also add everything above e.g. background2 in a div, give it an id and then get the height of that div to add to "top" for background2. It's exactly this code that I use for this https://eyesonpi.com website.

Answer (score 0):

Everything multiplied with 0 equals zero.
Why do not you use '-' to set variables value:

```
$('.wsite-section-bg-image').css('background-position-y', -(scrolled - 10) + 'px');
```

Comment: Weebs is not multiplying by 0 but by 0.1 which is the same as dividing by 10.

Comment: Hey Kobbe, looks like you have not seen the title and last sentance of the post.